# Celery subtask bound to different application executed remotely

Tags: python, celery

I have two Celery application instances with different configurations, let's say app1 and app2. Tasks from app1 are executed on a remote worker1. Tasks from app2 are executed on a remote worker2.

I am trying to execute a task from app1 with a subtask from app2 but the subtask is not getting executed.

My code is something like:

```
import app1.tasks as app1_tasks
import app2.tasks as app2_tasks

reference = 'foo'

success_callback = app2_tasks.bar.subtask(reference)

app1_tasks.foo.apply_async(
    args=(
        1, 2, 3, reference,
    ),
    link= success_callback,
)
```

Is there some way to make this work? I need to have two distinct Celery apps.

The callback task is not being run. I suppose it's because it's using a different app instance?

IMPORTANT: Both tasks are executed remotely on different workers! That's one of the reasons why I have two application instances.

Comment: The app is not serialized. The subtask is a Signature object which describes the arguments to the task and the execution options, when sent the app instance is removed, as that is a big complex structure which is expensive to serialize (and most certainly doesn't support json for example).  The worker will receive the subtask and use the app it was started with.  So: apps are local, they define how celery works in that process only.

Comment: Note: the subtask will be sent, but maybe with a different routing setting than you expected.  If app2 defines a different CELERY_ROUTES than app1, and the worker is started using app1 then the routing in app2 will not have any effect on the worker.   I guess that is a solvable problem if the subtask inherits the route early (but that may also clash with how others expect it to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep apps separated and have them communicate by:

1.have each worker listening to a different queue

```
$ celery worker -Q feeds
```

2.send a message using some [routing method](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/routing.html) to a specific app, manual example from docs:

```
>>> from feeds.tasks import import_feed
>>> import_feed.apply_async(args=['http://cnn.com/rss'],
...                         queue='feed_tasks',
...                         routing_key='feed.import')
```

3.[call task by name](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/faq.html#can-i-call-a-task-by-name) and keep apps code separated, form docs:

```
from celery.execute import send_task
send_task("tasks.add", args=[2, 2], kwargs={})
<AsyncResult: 373550e8-b9a0-4666-bc61-ace01fa4f91d>
```

Comment: How do I use `send_task` in case of `subtasks`? `app.send_task('myapp.send_push_notification', (json.dumps(payload1), ), link=app.send_task('differentapp.save_pn_response', (json.dumps(payload2), )))`